# .HTACCESS adding to slugs

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

So, I'm currently building a REST API in PHP.

I managed to get slugs working for the most part.
If I request `/api/admin/v1/users/1`, it will return the user I need.
However, I also need to be able to add to it, e.g. `/api/admin/v1/users/1/keys`.

The HTACCESS file managing the slug is in the folder itself (`/users/`).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

I tried adding another line, but I think I messed up (I'm not that advanced with HTACCESS)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/keys$ keys.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

This didn't do anything, it still returns the user object.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Because the first rule doesn't work either by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?slug=$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/keys$ keys.php?slug=$1 [L]
> ```

The first rule matches *everything*, so the second rule is never processed. But since the first rule matches *everything* it will also rewrite itself (to `user.php?slug=user.php`) on the second pass by the rewrite engine.

You can resolve these issues by making the regex more restrictive. From your example URL it looks like the `slug` is *numeric* - in which case you can restrict the regex to match digits (0-9) only.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d*)$ user.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/keys$ keys.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Note that the first rule also matches an empty URL-path, ie. no slug at all (as does your original rule). The second rule does not permit an empty slug (it would never match anyway).

Answer (score 0):

The second rule don't work because the L flag stay for: last - stop processing rules

So you need to edit to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?slug=$1 [QSA, L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/keys$ keys.php?slug=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Comment: How does this resolve the issue? All you've done is (incorrectly) add the `QSA` flag. You still have the `L` flag, which you've correctly stated prevents the second rule from being processed.